# Как правильно сверстать сквозной sidebar над контентом?

Tags: html, css

Прилетела вот такой макет http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2017/01/07/0003/2174/206974/74/20758cc53f.jpg
С первого взгляда ничего сложно, но вот сайдбар проходит сквозь все остальные слои.

### У меня только такая идея:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.section-block {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.section-block:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #f4c381;
}

.section-block__left {
  padding-left: 240px;
  height: 220px;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.sidebar div {
  z-index: 6;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar:after {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: '';
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<nav class="container">
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <div>
      очень длинный sidebar
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> очень длинный sidebar
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> очень длинный sidebar
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> очень длинный sidebar
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> очень длинный sidebar
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> очень длинный sidebar
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> очень длинный sidebar
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> очень длинный sidebar
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> очень длинный sidebar
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> очень длинный sidebar
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> очень длинный sidebar
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> очень длинный sidebar
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> очень длинный sidebar
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> очень длинный sidebar
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> очень длинный sidebar
      <br>
      <br>
      <br> очень длинный sidebar
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </aside>
</nav>

<div class="section-block header">
  <div class="container">
    <section class="content section-block__left">
      <br>
      <h1>Глазовский комбикормовый завод </h1>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section-block">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-block__left">
      layer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section-block">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-block__left">
      layer 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section-block">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section-block__left">
      layer 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Мой вариант мне не нравятся, может есть лучшее решение?

Comment: Вполне нормальное решение, как по мне

Answer (score 1):

Например, вот так:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-content {
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.main-content .sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
}
.main-content .sidecontent {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
  background: url(http://www.clipartkid.com/images/797/golden-wheat-fields-pictures-free-pictures-cnU7B9-clipart.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  padding-left: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-content">
 <div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
   <li>Option</li>
   <li>Option</li>
   <li>Option</li>
   <li>Option</li>
   <li>Option</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="sidecontent">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus unde architecto error sit laboriosam quos vero nostrum, voluptas ratione molestiae. Iure voluptatem laborum, commodi, tempora maiores est explicabo culpa maxime.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```